# Elseif returns #VALUE

Tags: vba, excel

Ok, so all I want to do is create a function to optimize how I can segment my PivotTable data. This data comes in different forms like "245896321 - Name", "name" or "name23123" and I want it to return the persons full name if the cells contains specific texts (person last name), but it only returns #VALUE!

Thanks in advance! You're beautiful!

Also I apologize if my coding hurts your eyes just started my adventure into the coding world two days ago, if you want to suggest modifications feel free! :)

```
Function Financeiro (Line) as String

   '=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*Person*", Line)), "Person Name")

If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("*Ormelli*", Line)) Then

 Financeiro = "Fernando Ormelli"

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("*Fortuna*", Line)) Then

 Financeiro = "Ricardo Fortuna"

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("*Manocchio*", Line)) Then

Financeiro = "Ricardo Manocchio"

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("*Stanquini*", Line)) Then

 Financeiro = "Helder Stanquini"

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("*Ivanete*", Line)) Then

 Financeiro = "Ivanete Leite"

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("*Freitas*", Line)) Then

 Financeiro = "João Freitas"

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("*Khan*", Line)) Then

 Financeiro = "Marcelo Khan"

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("*Filho*", Line)) Then

 Financeiro = "Marco Filho"

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("*Rocha*", Line)) Then

 Financeiro = "Natalia Rocha"

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("*Carvalho*", Line)) Then

 Financeiro = "Vinicius Carvalho"

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("*SAE*", Line)) Then

 Financeiro = "SAE"

ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.WorksheetFunction.Search("*Raphael*", Line)) Then

 Financeiro = "Raphael Vieira"

Else

Financeiro = "Manual"

End If

End Function
```

Comment: `Financeiro = Manual` : is `Manual` a variable defined somewhere else, or did you forget to add quotes around it?

Comment: I Just forgot to add quotes, but the error still persists. But thanks for that as well Tim!

Comment: Instead of calling your function from a worksheet cell, create a small Sub and call it from there: you will see where the error is.  `Sub Tester():Debug.Print Financeiro("blah"): End Sub`

Comment: *I apologize if my coding hurts your eyes just started my adventure into the coding world two days ago* - once you get your code to work as intended, come over to [codereview.se], you'll learn a ton! =)

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Application.WorksheetFunction.Search` will throw a runtime error if there's no match: try instead something like:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Application.Search("*Ormelli*", Line)) Then
'...
```

Omitting the `WorksheetFunction` switches the behavior from triggering a runtime error to instead returning an error value.

Or just use:

```
If Line Like "*Ormelli*" Then
'...
```

which I think is easier to follow.